# Excluir imagem do input file antes de enviar o form

Tags: php, jquery

estou usando o script abaixo

https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/yrvyf2gn/52/

Para fazer `múliplos uploads`.

Está funcionando corretamente. Eu seleciona (por exemplo) 3 imagens, depois removo 1, fico com 2. Enfim, o `JQuery` funciona que é uma beleza. Confiro no examinar elemento do chrome. 2 imagens. Tudo correto.

Mas quando dou um `submit` no formulário e pego `$_FILES` do outro lado vão as 3 imagens. Não as 2 que estavam no `html`.

Como resolver isso?

Será necessário pegar a div lista e envia-la como variável de alguma forma e desconsiderar o input file?

Comment: Como você está pegando os dados no php, pois a função de remover a imagem no javascript remove ela do html, mas a várivel no js ainda fica com as imagens

Comment: isso mesmo, vê a resposta que eu postei!

Comment: E aí amigo! Marque a sua resposta como certa. Abs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui.

Html

```
    <div id="multiple_upload">
        <input type="hidden" id="arquivos" name="arquivos" onChange="alert(this.value)" />
        <input type="file" multiple id="fotos"  name="fotos[]" />
        <div id="message">Selecionar fotos</div> 
        <div id="lista"></div>
    </div>
```

Nesse caso, eu envio as imagens depois de selecionadas e removidas através da variável `$arquivos` do `$_POST` gerado um `array` `php`

Eis a geração em JQuery:

```
var arquivos = new Array();

$(function(){
    $('#fotos').on('change',function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var totalFiles = $(this).get(0).files.length;

        if(totalFiles == 0) {
          $('#message').text('Selecionar Fotos' );
        }
        if ( totalFiles > 1) {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivos selecionados' );
        } else {
            $('#message').text( totalFiles+' arquivo selecionado' );
        }

        var htm='<ol>';

        for (var i=0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
             var c = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'item_white' : 'item_grey';
             var arquivo = $(this).get(0).files[i];
             var fileV = new readFileView(arquivo, i);

             arquivos.push(arquivo);                         

             htm += '<li class="'+c+'"><div class="box-images"><img  class="item elevate-image" data-img="'+i+'" data-id="'+id+'" border="0"></div><span>'+arquivo.name+'</span> <a href="javascript:removeFile('+i+',\''+id+'\')" class="remove">x</a></li>'+"\n";

         }


        htm += '</ol>';
           $('#lista').html(htm);
           $('#arquivos').val(arrayParaString(arquivos)); /*Aqui eu populo o campo do form id="arquivos" com um array trazido de arrayParaString*/
    });


});
```

arrayParaString:

```
function arrayParaString (array) {
    i = 0;
    string = "";

    while (array[i]) {
        string += array[i].name + '|';
        i++;
    }

    string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);

    return string;

}
```

só com o nome das imagens  depois comparo o `$_POST["arquivos"]` com o `$_FILES["fotos"]` e a que tiver no `$_FILES["fotos"]` que tem no `$_POST["arquivos"]` eu crio um array só com eles usando o método abaixo:

Php

```
public function arrayFotos($array1, $array2) {
   $novasFotos= array();

   if(is_array($array1) && count($array1) > 0) {
       $i = 0;
       foreach($array1 as $value1) {
           foreach($array2["name"] as $key =>$value2) {
               if ($value1 == $value2) {
                   //print $value1." - ".$value2."<br>";
                   if ( $array2["error"][$key] == 0) {
                       $novasFotos[$i]["name"] = $array2["name"][$key];
                       $novasFotos[$i]["type"] = $array2["type"][$key];
                       $novasFotos[$i]["tmp_name"] = $array2["tmp_name"][$key];
                       $novasFotos[$i]["error"] = $array2["error"][$key];
                       $novasFotos[$i]["size"] = $array2["size"][$key];
                   }
                  $i++;
                  break;                                 
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return $novasFotos;
}
```